# Batch Script – Delete Characters in a String till delimiter

Tags: batch-file

I am desperately looking for a solution to the following problem:

I have a batch file that reads a path from a txt file and saves it as a string. For example: pathname=C:\User\Software\v1.1\Test\abcdefg

Now I just want to get the path and delete everything from the last "\". So a folder above the final folder in the path:
result=C:\User\Software\v1.1\Test

I have a hard time with batch scripts, I hope you can help me.

```
set result=%pathname:*\=%
```

This deletes the chars befor the **first "\"**: User\Software\v1.1\Test\abcdefg

Is there a way to give back every char before the **last "\"** like: C:\User\Software\v1.1\Test

The paths will differ in length everytime.

Comment: Have you tried, ```For %%G In ("%pathname%") Do For %%H In ("%%~dpG.") Do Echo %%~fH```?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "pathname=C:\User\Software\v1.1\Test\abcdefg"
for %%e in ("%pathname%") do set "result=%%~dpe"
SET "result=%result:~0,-1%"
ECHO +%result%+
GOTO :eof
```

Treating the pathname as though it was a filename.

The `+` at either end of the report shows there are no extra spaces in the result.